# How to understand the logic behind the assignment of variables?

Tags: c

I am a beginner, how can I understand this error?

Method 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int a=b=c=6;
printf("%d\n",a);
printf("%d\n",b);
printf("%d\n",c);
return 0;
}
```

It displays an error:

```
prog.c:5:7: error: ‘b’ undeclared (first use in this function)
int a=b=c=6;
       ^
prog.c:5:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for             
each function it appears in
prog.c:5:9: error: ‘c’ undeclared (first use in this function)
int a=b=c=6;
         ^
```

Method 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int a,b,c;
printf("%d\n",a);
printf("%d\n",b);
printf("%d\n",c);
return 0;
}
```

My output is

```
0
0
0
```

Is this due to return 0? Would someone please add examples for better understanding?

Comment: I think you really should take a book and reading some basic introduction about the language, answering your questions won't help you because you need a basic understanding which you don't have at the moment.

Comment: `int c=6, b=c, a=b;` is probably what you're shooting for. You seem to be confusing declaration with initialization, and assignment. Stare at that a moment and it will make sense. Unrelated, the second method invokes *undefined behavior*. The values of a, b, and c are *indeterminate*. That you manage to get three zeros for output is *not* standard-based.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes,I understood the problem.

Comment: 'I am a beginner' fine, so don't try to do anything 'clever' until you gain more skill and experience.  When you reach that stage, you will know to not try to do anything 'clever' anyway.

Comment: @MartinJames Sure Sir, I was just experimenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is on this line:

```
int a=b=c=6;
```

C requires that a variable be declared before using it, here you try to use b before it is declared. For example, unlike the above the following is legal:

```
int a = 1, b = a;
```

because the assignment to b uses a variable that has already been declared.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get an IDE
2. Read a book. Google. Don't ask questions without researching for an existing solution. I know it's easy to ask, but researching can help you more than just getting your answer.

Now to your answer. Perhaps, https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson1.html
Scroll down, read about variables.

Variables are declared as:

```
int a; 
int b;
int c;
```

Variables can also be declared all in one line,

```
int a, b, c;
```

You could also assign values to your variables when you declare them.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
```

Or, you could declare & assign them values all in one line:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
```

The "int" above, is a datatype. It tells the compiler what kind of variable you are declaring. There are various datatypes in C: int, float, char, double, etc. These are the fundamental data types. There also derived datatypes, etc, etc, etc.

If you do not assign a value to a variable, and you just print it, it will print a junk value (in your case 0, it can be anything though). Try assigning values in your method #2 as I did above and you will see the difference.

The return 0, is used to specify the exit code of your application. 0 means the application exited successfully. In case of failure, a value other than 0 is returned, but anyways.

Good luck. 
Learn to use google.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show you some examples to assign values.

Example 01

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int a, b, c;
    a = b = c = 6;

    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Example 02

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int a = 6, b = 6, c = 6;

    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

The next code is the same you did. You can't assume they're always 0. C language won't initialize them automatically, so the variables have just garbage.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int a, b, c;

    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I understood the concept.

Comment: Note that `void main()` is not portable; it only applies on Windows.  Everywhere else, it is `int main()` — and `int main()` also works on Windows, as long as you return `0` (for success) at the end.

Comment: Maybe it worked like that in the past, but now I'm using Linux and it's working normally. My compiler is gcc version 7.2.0.

Comment: Isn't it a bad practice to use 'void main()'. I learned that  'int main(void)' are used over 'void main()'. Have a look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-int-main-int-mainvoid/  and here too:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fine-write-void-main-cc/ @JonathanLeffler